# Cheaper email solution than Google Apps

Tags: email, google-workspace

I'm designing a website for a Canadian political organization which isn't very well funded. While Google's solution for nonprofits is pretty solid, either Canadian or political organizations don't meet the requirements. Also, I expect to have more than 10 accounts. Besides $50/year for each account is way too much for a small nonprofit organization.

What would be a cheap, solid email solution?

Comment: See [this meta question](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/627/where-to-buy-whatever-is-this-low-quality) for why this question and questions like this are closed.

Answer (score 2):

Office 365 is $6 per user per month, but for that money you can have shared web hosting, which will also include unlimited e-mail. If you just need e-mail the hosting option would probably be much cheaper.

Comment: Thing is, I'll use Heroku for hosting so no email with them, and $6/month > $50/year.

Comment: You can buy e-mail only packages. My (Dutch) domain provider wants 2 euro a month for 30 boxes and 1,5Gb storage. There must be Canadian parties offering this.

Answer (score 1):

If you own a VPS, try setting up [hMailServer](http://www.hmailserver.com/).

**Update:**

Was thinking the same. Great free option. I use it for my own VPS.
The only catch is its Windows only, and I bet the cheap solution mentioned won't be using Windows likely.